# Configuring unattended-upgrades Help

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I just got this update.
I don't know which one to choose from.
I have a dual boot and i am new to it so don't wanna mess things up.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEh4i.png)

Comment: Do you recall changing any unattended-upgrades settings? (you probably did, or you would not get the question). If you do not recall, then pick the first option.

Comment: Actually this is the first time i am seeing this, new to Linux stuffs :) .. I know which one to select but was not sure because i got a dual boot and don't wanna mess up my boot loader and my windows.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You say “this”, but what is this? You do not show us it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option is the safest one: *Install the package maintainer's version*. This option gets the package updates as usual when updating the installed software. The other options are non-default options.